# Java Arraylist printing every other number in a list

Tags: java

This is my code for printing the random numbers in an arraylist:

```
public void printList()
{
    System.out.println("The numbers on the list: ") ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < aList.size() ; i++)
    {
        System.out.print( aList.get(i) + "  ") ;
    }
    System.out.println("\n") ;                
}
```

How would I print every other number of this same list? By using a do-while loop?

Comment: instead of i++ do i += 2

Answer (score 3):

Put additional if statement inside your for block which would check for parity: if (i % 2 == 0) { System.out.print(... }

Answer (score 2):

Above approach is ineffecient. Just increment the index by 2

```
public void print()
{
    System.out.println("The numbers on the list: ") ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < aList.size() ; i+=2)
    {
        System.out.print( aList.get(i) + "  ") ;
    }
    System.out.println();                
}
```

Comment: Both are inefficient with LinkedList. Prefer iteration over random element access and separate counter:

public void print() {
    System.out.println("The numbers on the list: ") ;
    int i = 0;
    for (Object o : aList) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print( o + "  ") ;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println();                
}

Comment: Didn't they ask about ArrayList? Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Chris `Edit: This will cause an outOfBoundsException if aList.size() is odd.` Not on my Java! Can you write me an example?

Comment: @Joey Yes, they did, but it's still good to know how usage of different kinds of lists differ.